# openpyxl thread safe?

Tags: python, thread-safety, openpyxl

Is openpyxl thread safe?
I'm hoping to have one thread changing the worksheet while another thread saves at regular intervals. I was wondering if I needed to add a lock object around the changing and saving operations or whether that is already built in to openpyxl. I did not see anything in the documentation nor any previous questions about threads in openpyxl.

After reading your answer I ran the following test:

```
import threading 
import random 
import time 
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook() 

class openpyxlwriting ( threading.Thread): 

    def run ( self ): 

        global wb
        ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
        c = 1 
        for a in range(100):
            for b in range(10000):
                ws.cell(column = a,row=b).value = c
                c += 1
            print "row ",a

class openpyxlsaving ( threading.Thread): 

    def run ( self ): 

        global wb

        for a in range(1000): 
            wb.save('test.xlsx')
            print "saved"

openpyxlwriting().start()
time.sleep(1)
openpyxlsaving ().start()
```

which gave me the following trasback:
[trasback.png](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aaet4xg5es7bpva/openpyxl%20trasback.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to see if I could test this, so I created the simple program below that generates a bunch of threads that attempt to read and write the same cell, with random sleeps thrown in.

I didn't see any OS errors that might indicate a problem.  On the other hand, I did see some behavior that I didn't quite understand.  As the thread count increased, the number of loops completed decreased.  So, for example, thread 100 only completed 8 passes through the loop.  This might be some sort of an error on my part, or it might indicate an issue with thread safety.

Anyway, this should give you a start in testing it yourself, if you feel so inclined.

```
import threading
import random
import time
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
testcell = ws.cell('B9')
counter = 1

class openpyxlworker ( threading.Thread):

    def run ( self ):

        global wb     
        global testcell
        global counter

        for a in range(1000):
            time.sleep(random.random()/100)
            writing = random.randrange(1, 1000)
            testcell.value = writing
            time.sleep(random.random()/100)
            reading = testcell.value          
            print "Thread " + str(counter) + " wrote " + str(writing) + " and read " + str(reading)
            time.sleep(random.random()/100)
            wb.save('test.xlsx')

        counter = counter + 1

for b in range(100):
    openpyxlworker().start()
```

Comment: Based on your experimentation with openpyxl 1.5.8... reads and writes are thread safe but not fully concurrent. I.e. no errors but slower performance per thread as the number of threads goes up. However saving operations are not thread safe. The save operation crashes if there is a write operation during a save operation.

Comment: That's a great idea, but I tried to reproduce it (see updated app above) and could not get it to crash.

Answer (score 5):

> "OpenPyXl is thread safe; Workbooks can be created concurrently by
>   different threads. However, each workbook should only be modified by
>   one thread at a time."

Form https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/228/

Comment: Tells me access denied for that link.
What I'm personally interested in, is having a thread per sheet, as I'm filling in a 10+ pages sheet from IO-Bound sources.